# Optimization with box constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have the following convex optimization problem

```
minimize f(x)
```

subject to box constraints `x ∈ [a, b]`.

I have already solved the unconstrained problem using BFGS and I want to use the same(BFGS method) to solve the problem with box constraints. Can anyone please suggest the way on how to accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I’m not sure what software/language/environment you’re using. In Python, you can use [SciPy’s `minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) function with the L-BFGS-B method, which allows for bound constraints. However, why do you want to use (modified) BFGS? This is a convex optimization problem—there are _lots_ of convex-specific algorithms that are very efficient.

Comment: @DavidM. I have just learnt about the quasi-newton method and was trying to implement it. I just got curious if I can use the same in case of box constraints. I am using FORTAN for this.

Comment: @DavidM. Can you please tell me about other efficient algorithms?

Comment: Are you implementing the algorithms on your own to learn about them / for practice? (Look up the book “Convex Optimization” by Boyd and Vandenberghe—it’s a very good general reference for convex optimization)